# Should I set ConfigMap for pod or deployment in GKE?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm starting to work with Google Kubernetes Engine.
I have successfully started up an app with a deployment config.
GKE set up a pod to run the containerized app inside it.

I want to load a config map into the pod as environment variables.
From the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-pod-environment-variables-using-configmap-data) it says to load the config map to the `pod`.

But shouldn't I load it to the `deployment`?
If the pod is restarted, all the changes are discarded, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you deployed your pods through a deployment, yes, you should put them in your `Deployment` definition under the `template` for your pods. Most people use the Deployments, DaemonSets, StatefulSets or HPAs abstractions to manage the Kubernetes pods because the can take care of the scaling, redundancy, replicas, etc.

The Kubernetes documentation uses pods quite a bit as examples and they do work. So if you wonder what happens if you add ConfigMap to a pod. Then you will have to manage the pods yourself, that means deleting, and recreating the pods manually. For example to delete `kubectl delete pod <pod-name>` and to create `kubectl create -f <pod-definition>`

Comment: Thanks, do you know why `envFrom` doesn't work while `env` works?

Comment: If you use envFrom you should also reference the configMap used as shown in this example: 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#configure-all-key-value-pairs-in-a-configmap-as-container-environment-variables